# How can I remove the time next to Date in jtable using jdatechooser? my Datatype in my access is date/time

Tags: java, ms-access, jtable, jdatechooser

I'm new to programming. How can I remove the zero next to the date (2022-04-21 00:00:00.000000)?

here is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdf.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());
((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText(date);
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
model.addRow(new Object[]{date});
pst.setString(7, date);
```

Comment: You mean `get rid of the time component` within the date string? Well, that's exactly what your code does:  `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); jDateChooser1.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd"); String date =                               sdf.format(jDateChooser1.getDate()); System.out.println(date);`.

Comment: hello, good evening. I already try that but it's still an error. @DevilsHnd

Comment: What error? You should edit your question and provide the exact error message.